# Applying multiple aggregations at once in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a `PCollection` of a key-value pair where the value is a Double.
I need to compute the total number of values and their average.

I see there are two transforms - `Count` and `Mean`. But I can't find a way to apply them simultaneously in a GroupBy operation.

It looks like my options are to either implement my own combine method that will implement both counting and averaging, or to apply Count and Mean separately and then join them on the original key.

Is there a third way to do it?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the proper way to do that is to write your own DoFn and use it after a GroupByKey transformation:

```
static class CountAndMean extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterator<Double>>, String> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        long count = 0L;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(Double v: c.element().getValue()){
           sum += v.doubleValue();
           count += 1L;
        }
        double mean = sum/count;
        String out = c.element().getKey() + "," + String.valueOf(mean) + "," + String.valueOf(count); 
        c.output(out);
   }

PCollection<KV<String, Double>> inCol = ... ;
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<Double>>> perKeyCol = inCol.apply(GroupByKey.<String, Double>create());
PCollection<String> outCol = perKeyCol.apply(ParDo.named("CountAndMean").of(new CountAndMean()));
```

Comment: But wouldn't the count operation return 1 (since all keys are now distinct)?

Comment: Oups, that's true here is another solution based on GroupByKey.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought about too. I was hoping I can reuse the `Count` and `Mean` operations..